# How can I train YOLO v7 using only the CPU?

Tags: python, cpu, yolov7

I am trying to train the [YOLO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_detection#Methods) v7 on a custom dataset on my Mac.

I'm new to Python and have some issues.
I've created the [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) in the project directory with Python 3.7 and prepared my dataset all like in the instructions.

After running a command `python train.py --workers 1 --device cpu --batch-size 1 --epochs 20 --img 640 640 --data data/custom_data.yaml --hyp data/hyp.scratch.custom.yaml --cfg cfg/training/yolov7-custom.yaml --name yolov7-custom --weights yolov7.pt`

I have an error on 73% progress.

```
/Users/username/Documents/PROJECT DIR/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/autocast_mode.py:162: UserWarning: User provided device_type of 'cuda', but CUDA is not available. Disabling
  warnings.warn('User provided device_type of \'cuda\', but CUDA is not available. Disabling')


  0/19        0G   0.03661   0.02227         0   0.05888         3       640:  73%|███████████████████       | 38/52 [04:50<01:47,  7.65s/it]


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 616, in <module>
    train(hyp, opt, device, tb_writer)
  File "train.py", line 363, in train
    loss, loss_items = compute_loss_ota(pred, targets.to(device), imgs)  # loss scaled by batch_size
  File "/Users/username/Documents/PROJECT DIR/yolov7/utils/loss.py", line 585, in __call__
    bs, as_, gjs, gis, targets, anchors = self.build_targets(p, targets, imgs)
  File "/Users/username/Documents/PROJECT DIR/yolov7/utils/loss.py", line 786, in build_targets
    matching_bs[i] = torch.tensor([], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.int64)
  File "/Users/username/Documents/PROJECT DIR/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 210, in _lazy_init
    raise AssertionError("Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled")
AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled
```

How can I properly resolve this? I understand some libraries in project or venv still trying to use [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA). How can I solve it using only the CPU?

I've already tried to manually set the device as the CPU in file *yolov7/utils/torch_utils.py*, but nothing changed.